# Table not refreshing using ajax

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I an experimenting with MVC. I have a view which contains a dropdownlist and a table.
When I select an option from the dropdownlist, I want to get the data from my controller and update the view:

View:

```
    <div>
        <h2>Current Print Statistics</h2>
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.DropDownList("LogTypes", new SelectList(Model.LogTypes, "Value", "Text"), new
            {
                id = "logType",
                data_url = Url.Action("GetStatistics", "Home")
            })

            <table id="modelTable" class="table table-condensed">
                <tr>
                    <th>RequestedOn</th>
                    <th>PrintedOn</th>
                    <th>Message</th>
                    <th>Success</th>
                    <th>TemplateName</th>
                </tr>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model.PrintLogs)
                    {
                        string css = (item.Success) ? "success" : "danger";
                        string link = (item.Success) ? "www.google.com" : string.Empty;
                        <tr class="@css">
                            <td>@item.RequestedOn</td>
                            <td>@item.PrintedOn</td>
                            <td>@item.Message</td>
                            @if (item.Success)
                            {
                                <td>@item.Success</td>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <td>@Html.ActionLink("False", "Index", "LogView", new { id = item.LogID }, null)</td>
                            }
                            <td>@item.TemplateName</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        }
    </div>
</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#logType').change(function () {
        console.log($(this).data('url'));
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        var table = $('#modelTable');


        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).data('url'),
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            context: table,
            data: { value: selectedValue },
            success: function (result) {
                $.each(result.PrintLogs,
                    function (index, log) {
                        $('<tr/>', {
                            html: $('<td/>', {
                                html: log.RequestedOn
                            }).after($('<td/>', {
                                html: log.PrintedOn
                            })).after($('<td/>', {
                                html: log.Success
                            })).after($('<td/>', {
                                html: log.Message
                            })).after($('<td/>', {
                                html: log.TemplateName
                            }))
                        }).appendTo(tableBody);
                    }
                );
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetStatistics(string value)
{          
        var request = LogTypeRequest.Last24H;
        if (value == "0") request = LogTypeRequest.Last24H;
        if (value == "1") request = LogTypeRequest.LastWeek;
        if (value == "2") request = LogTypeRequest.LastMonth;

        var model = new PrintServerModel
        {
            LogTypes = new List<ListItem>
                {
                    new ListItem() {Text = "Last 24 Hours", Value = "0"},
                    new ListItem() {Text = "Last Week", Value = "1"},
                    new ListItem() {Text = "Last Month", Value = "2"}
                },
            PrintLogs = PrintServerService.GetPrinterLog(request)
        };
        return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Now when I try to debug in chrome, when the line $.ajax({ is reached it seems to jump to the end.

Ideally what I want is to display the data on start up and then when the user selects something from the dropdown, refresh the data.

Any help greafully appreciated!!

Comment: less code more answer

Comment: ``appendTo("#modelTable tbody");``

Answer (score 0):

Odds are there is an error from the json call, you should add .done or error: to the end of it so you can see what your error is.

also there is a tab in chrome debug tool for watching the network calls, you may be able to see the response from the call in there with some additional details.

just looking over the ajax call, may want to change to have

```
data: JSON.stringify( { value: selectedValue }),
```

if you get more info i will do what i can to better my answer.